# A case of click-through closing vandalism

Tags: discussion, support

Here is a case how the current review-system ruins the content on SO.

The question [Merge alternate elements from two lists in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678158/how-to-write-the-mergealt-in-prolog) tagged as [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) **only** has been closed by 5 individuals. Four of them never contributed anything to [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog). And one individual, the moderator https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard has 7 upvotes for [two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1288%20%5Bprolog%5D): In one, he states that he has **not** read a book he recommends, in the other he states that he has not tried some IDE.

The closed question is clearly not the best formulated on SO, but it is understandable. And there are two useful answers which do not give away everything but help beginners. Brief, I cannot see a reason why this question has been closed.

Comment: I don't know prolog either, but that's obviously a bad question. Remember: Closing is not an end state. If the question can be reformulated to be a better question it can (and should) be re-opened.

Comment: _"The closed question is clearly not the best formulated on SO"_. Precisely.

Comment: The question amounts to, "Please do my work for me". It takes no knowledge of prolog to see that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: But even to such a question there is a good answer. And both answers are very good.

Comment: @ÄlËverett: Revent I have seen that closed questions were removed on tag prolog. So the work from the two very constructive answerers is threatened

Comment: @false - the question should not need good answers to redeem it. It should be good in and of itself.

Comment: @Ben: Does this justify that the two very good answers will be deleted too?

Comment: @false Voting to close an question does not mean the answers are not good.  The closed question will probably remain on the site.  There is a separate process to delete questions.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: @false Who says they will be deleted? That's absolutely not a given.

Comment: @ChrisF: So the presence of answers is irrelevant?

Comment: @false Questions are closed because the question is bad. That the answers are good does not change that at all. So yes, that's irrelevant.

Comment: @Bart: See my profile for one such question. Instead of permitting a reformulation, it was closed.

Comment: @false - to a certain extent. If there are good answers then perhaps there should be more effort made to improve the question, but the review queue doesn't show you them.

Comment: @cadrell0: See my profile for a question that has been deleted already.

Comment: @false: Could you link to that question specifically?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: You find it in: http://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false There, it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454022/a-prologue-for-prolog

Comment: Questions with good answers aren't supposed to be deleted and usually aren't. From the ["Access to moderator tools" page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools): "Before voting to delete, please check that there are no good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers"

Comment: Looking at Billthelizard's answers', how is recommending something that you havent used a good answer ?

Comment: Your question was deleted for an entirely different reason ("what is your favorite" questions aren't acceptable on SO, and this has been generally accepted and agreed upon for a long time). It has absolutely nothing to do with the closed "do my homework" question other than that both involve Prolog.

Comment: @AshRj Who says it's a good answer? Please note that the question is from 2008, a time at which this site and what was appropriate was significantly different from today. I'm sure Bill would agree it's not a gem of an answer. But that's really not under discussion here.

Comment: @AshRj: I mentioned Billthelizard's answers only because they were **the only** evidence on SO for a relation to tag:prolog of those 5 individuals.

Comment: That question was flagged as a part of the [tag:homework] tag cleanup effort.  You don't need to know Prolog to recognize it as a particularly poor question.  It restates a homework question, then says "I don't really know recursion, so someone please help me!"  That's about as close to zero effort on the part of the OP as you can get.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: My deleted question is evidence that closed questions get deleted after some time.

Comment: @false That **some** closed questions get deleted after some time. But by no means all. And the more valuable the answers are, the less likely it is that this will happen.

Comment: @false: Your question received three delete votes from the community. That's the reason it was deleted. What does that have to do with the other question you link to?

Comment: Now, This might just be my lack of `prolog` experience speaking, but that question looks an awfully lot like a "give me teh codes" question

Comment: @DavidRobinson: My point here was only that questions eventually get deleted so putting an effort into answering it might be not worth the effort. (That question you mention also got about 14 or more upvotes.)

Comment: @false I agree that it's not worth putting too much effort into answering bad questions. That's the risk people take when they do so.

Comment: @false: closed questions *can't* get new answers (that's sort of the whole point) so what does "answering it might not be worth the effort" have to do with it? Anyway, the "do my homework" question remains a very poor question, and I don't regret voting to close.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Bart i didnt really look beyond the answer and up-votes on both the pages. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 12):

This is [the question, verbatim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678158/how-to-write-the-mergealt-in-prolog). Let's have a look at it:

```
<question>
```

> Write a Prolog function mergealt(X,Y,Z), that makes the list Z a merger of alternate
>   elements from the lists X and Y. and the input and out put will like below:

```
?- mergealt([1,2,3,4],[6,7,8],Z).
Z = [1, 7, 3] .
?- mergealt([1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9],Z).
Z = [1, 7, 3, 9] .
?- mergealt([1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9,10],Z).
Z = [1, 7, 3, 9] .
```

I don't really know recursion, so someone please help me!

```
</question>
```

The first part of the question is the assignment the user is trying to complete. That, alone doesn't make the question *bad*, however *that's all there is to the question* other than an explanation that the author does not know recursion and wants help.

As nothing indicates to the contrary, most would assume that by 'help', the user would be quite happy if someone were to give them the solution to the exercise. There is no actual question to be found.

Even if I had an in depth knowledge of Prolog, I don't think I could see how this question fits within our quality standards.

Per a section of our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) that all new users asking questions must read:

> #### Do your homework
>
> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your
>   question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found
>   and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken
>   the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious
>   answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant
>   answer!

Take a look at the text given under the close reason on the question:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
>   be reasonably answered in its current form.

Incomplete, vague and overly broad clearly apply - there was nothing sinister about the closing of this question. Four users and the moderator that cast the final vote decided that the question, as asked, did not meet our minimum quality standards.

The question could be re-opened if:

- The user gave a more detailed explanation of what they don't understand
- The user showed some attempt to try and solve the problem, which is very useful to us to figure out where they are stuck
- The user ultimately asked a question

All of this is something that the *user* needs to do, we can't do it for the user because (again), we have no idea where they are actually stuck.

While I do abstain from close votes (especially as a moderator) if I'm at all unsure, there's no ambiguity here. The question as asked is simply not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Bleh. “How do I get started” is also a valid question, and suits the existing answers. The answers are useful, so let's adjust the question and keep it, eh?

Answer (score 10):

> The closed question is clearly not the best formulated on SO

Formulation is one issue. But this question does not go beyond a "please do my (home)work for me" request. It is not a good question, if it's a question at all. It can stand with significant improvement. What has the OP tried? Where is he stuck? "I don't really know recursion" doesn't fit that bill.

> And there are two useful answers which do not give away everything but help beginners.

Excellent. Some knowledgeable users managed to contribute something positive to a question that is not all that good. Whether or not they should have put in this effort is debatable, but well done for them.

> I cannot see a reason why this question has been closed.

Because the question is bad. As simple as that. Most of us can see that. That the questin received answers of value does not change that at all. Knowledge of Prolog is not required at all for this particular evaluation. Closed questions are not dead, but this one needs significant improvement for it to be reopened.

In short, what you're seeing is not vandalism at all. It's appropriate community moderation. Want to see this reopened? Then help the OP reformulate his question so it can stand up to scrutiny.

Comment: **"help the OP reformulate his question so it can stand up to scrutiny"** couldn't agree more. I think **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10678158/edit "click to, well, edit the question")** is the way to go in cases like this

Comment: @gnat: Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Note though that even with your editing efforts, still some effort is required on behalf of the OP. The formulation has improved. The question itself however hasn't.